# Trouble Creating an executable Java Jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have the following Java code. It does what it is meant to do, but I am having problems creating a jar file.

```
import java.io.*;
public class openfile{
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
                String line;
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
                ("c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\"+ "shares.bat /A");
                 BufferedReader input =
                 new BufferedReader
                 (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                 input.close();
                }
           catch (Exception err) {
                  err.printStackTrace();
               }
    }
}
```

It compiles no problem, It runs no problem when using java openfile. The problem arises when I try to create a jar file using the following commands:

```
  jar cf MyJar.jar manifest.txt openfile.java openfile.class
```

However when I try to run the jar using

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

I get the following error message:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from MyJar.jar
```

The text of manifest.txt is as follows:

```
Main-Class: openfile
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I got the problem i believe.

In your manifest.txt file

The text of manifest.txt is as follows:

```
Main-Class: openfile
```

You need to provide a line break after last line

**So just type Enter (<-) (carriage return) after this line.**

```
Main-Class: openfile
```

Refer to [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) sun documentation. here is an excerpt.

> Warning: The text file must end with a
>   new line or carriage return. The last
>   line will not be parsed properly if it
>   does not end with a new line or
>   carriage return.

I verified with this and it works. 
Hope this helps .

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for responding. Tried this still getting the same error. I started from scratch. Deleted the old manifest.txt, typed the line in a new file and hit the Enter button (so that cursor is on a new line), saved the file and created new jar file. Made no difference.

Comment: I think u have not used 
**`jar cfm   MyJar.jar manifest.txt openfile.class openfile.java`**

u should use **m** option, or else it will provide a default manifest file without class definition.  

I rechecked again.. i worked perfect.. u r missing the  **m** option

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have a class openfile with a main method declared, then this should work:

```
jar cvef MyJar.jar openfile openfile.class
```

If you already have a manifest and want to include it, then try this:

```
jar cvmf MyJar.jar manifest.txt openfile.class
```

Comment: Hi,

Tried both versions of this answer, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The Content of your Manifest File must be this:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: openfile

A blank line must be left after these two lines as not leaving it might create problem.

Comment: Hi,
Tried this and still having the same problems. If you look at the two answers above it does not seem to want to work. Is it possible a configuration problem on my system?

Comment: Try extracting the file and see the content. The content must be:
1) Meta-Inf Folder containing manifest.txt file
2) And otherfile.class file (outside meta-inf folder)

If that is there, it should work.

Comment: HI Logan, Extracted the jar file and it contains the openfile.class file and a META-INF folder that contains a MANIFEST file containing the following (over 3 lines): 

    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Created-By: 1.6.0_21 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
    Main-Class: openfile

Yet I am still getting the same error. Is it possible there is something wrong with my java configuration?

Comment: I am not sure about java configuration. Remove the line created by........... and make sure there is a blank line after main-class line. If that blank line will not be there, the jar will not work. ( By blank line I mean, go to line after Main-Class and press enter once). Wish u luck.

Comment: Also, my Manifest files extension is .MF, try changing it, if it works, let me know.